# How to give alert for user for select at least any one radio button?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rlist" runat="server"          
  style="z-index: 1; left: 194px; top: 69px; position: absolute;
  height: 21px; width: 110px" 
  RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black">
       <asp:ListItem Value="True">Yes</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="False">No</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

This is my coding if user has not selected any one radio button means it will show alert in JavaScript.

Comment: How you are validating it? clientside or serverside?

Comment: clientside only using javascript...if user select atleast anyone radiobutton otherwise it will show alert using javascript....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it is tested please change your textbox Client Id and radio button ID. It fully works.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                function buttonclick()
                {
                    var txt1 = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>');
                    var txt2 = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox2.ClientID %>');
     

 var b = new Boolean(validateRadioButtonList('<%= rlist.ClientID %>'))
                     if (b == false)
                      {
                         return false;
                    
                      }
                    if (txt1.value == "")
                    {
                        alert("please enter text1");
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (txt2.value == "")
                    {
                        alert("please enter text2");
                        return false;
                    }
                    
                }
                function validateRadioButtonList(radioButtonListId)
                {
                    var listItemArray = document.getElementsByName(radioButtonListId);
                    var isItemChecked = false;
        
                    for (var i = 0; i < listItemArray.length; i++)
                    {
                        var listItem = listItemArray[i];
        
                        if (listItem.checked)
                        {
                            //alert(listItem.value);
                            isItemChecked = true;
                        }
                    }
        
                    if (isItemChecked == false)
                    {
                        alert('Nothing is checked!');
        
                        return false;
                    }
        
                    return true;
                }
            
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rlist" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 194px; top: 69px; position: absolute; height: 21px; width: 110px" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black">
 <asp:ListItem Value="True">Yes</asp:ListItem> 
<asp:ListItem Value="False">No</asp:ListItem> 
</asp:RadioButtonList> 
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="return buttonclick();" Text="Button" />
            </div>
            </form>
</body>
```

Comment: really thank u  friend...but i already written function on button click...then how do add this to that...sry i have one above radiobuttonlist and two textboxes..i already wrote validation for that textboxes using javascript..i dont know how to do validate radio button list..so pls tell for this

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="txtapprovedVacancy" runat="server" CssClass="txtusrnam" ></asp:TextBox>

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" CssClass="txtusrnam" ></asp:TextBox>

Comment: <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="return validate() ;"
                  
                   onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />

Comment: sry not able to find that..i think you didnt get my point..i have a form in that one radiobuttonlist,two textboxes..i need to validate for these three in single button click.if user didnt select anyone radiolist or textboxes are empty means it will show alert for these errors.. so sry please give solution for this..

Comment: using only javascript for validation for textboxes and radiobuttonlist in single buttonclick

Comment: nikhil u have given only button in that form but i asked two textboxes with that radiolist..if the textboxes are empty it will show alert when click on btnSubmit using javascript

Comment: Now it is Tested Pls change your both textbox Client Id and radiobutton Client IT fully Works

Comment: Nikhil reallly thanks alot...now only its working...thanks alot my friend

Comment: sorry still i didnt get answer..its not validating.i have first radiolist and then two textboxes in my form...how to do???wats the problem really i dont know...please guide me...

Comment: sry my friend its not validating textboxes..i checked..pls you see..i don the reason..pls check it let me know...really sry my friend its checked only radiolist not for textboxes...

Comment: still not working friend....im having radiolist like this..<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rlist" runat="server" 
                    
                    style="z-index: 1; left: 194px; top: 69px; position: absolute; height: 21px; width: 110px" 
                    RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="True">Yes</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="False">No</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>

Comment: sry my friend...im showing this form in popup using ajax modal..its checked radiolist after that its not going for validating textboxes...i don know the reason..sry for asking silly questions

Comment: give me ur aspx code i wll chk u r doing something wrong my code is 100% correct problem is from urside.not frm myside..

Comment: sry myside only wrong...really sry for the trouble...really thanks for ypur valuable comments........sry friend

Comment: do u have any idea about stored procedure and sql database?

Comment: in database i have table with three columns id,Design,Des...using stored procedure,insert data into that two columns (design,des both r in varchar)by taking the last (id)value and incremented by 1(ie next row)..suppose 4 rows r already presented in that table,if i give datas means it will insert in 5 th row.. it will repeat  one by one if i give data also:)got it friend???

Comment: sorry friend id in that column should be primary key...so i need insert the record by incrementing id +1....pls guide me

Comment: means ur records are inserted two times

Comment: How to return 1 if username exists and 0 in other case? Here is what I've tried.

Comment: How to return 1 if username exists and 0 in other case? Here is what I've tried.

Comment: i didnt get what u want want to ask

Comment: string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload.FileName); string Imagename = objUser.UserID + filename; FileUpload.SaveAs(@"D:\Shop_Web_21-6-12\ShopMonkey\Images" + Imagename); uploaded file is not stored in given physical path?above is my coding.

Answer (score 2):

Use Validators

```
   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator   
        ID="ReqiredFieldValidator1"  
        runat="server"  
        ControlToValidate="RadioButtonList1"  
        ErrorMessage="Select your choice!"  
        >  
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: This is the best approach as you get the code already implemented for free - you can use a ValidationSummary with ShowMessageBox set to true to have the error popup in a alert box

Comment: string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload.FileName); string Imagename = objUser.UserID + filename; FileUpload.SaveAs(@"D:\Shop_Web_21-6-12\ShopMonkey\Images" + Imagename); uploaded file is not stored in given physical path?above is my coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery to validate this.

The statement `$('#RadioButtonList1 input:checked').val()` will give you the text of selected item otherwise null.

Comment: sorry friend to validate in javascript only....and show alert..so please kindly guide me in this

Comment: still not working friend....im having radiolist like this..<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rlist" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 194px; top: 69px; position: absolute; height: 21px; width: 110px" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black"> <asp:ListItem Value="True">Yes</asp:ListItem> <asp:ListItem Value="False">No</asp:ListItem> </asp:RadioButtonList>

Comment: string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload.FileName); string Imagename = objUser.UserID + filename; FileUpload.SaveAs(@"D:\Shop_Web_21-6-12\ShopMonkey\Images" + Imagename); uploaded file is not stored in given physical path?above is my coding.

Answer (score -1):

```
<form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server">
 <asp:RadioButtonList id="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
  <asp:ListItem Text="Excellent" Value="1" />
  <asp:ListItem Text="Good" Value="2" />
  <asp:ListItem Text="Average" Value="3" />
  <asp:ListItem Text="Poor" Value="4" />
  <asp:ListItem Text="Very Poor" Value="5" />
 </asp:RadioButtonList>
 <input type="button" onclick="onButtonClick();" value="Validate">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function onButtonClick()
{
 return validateRadioButtonList('<%= RadioButtonList1.ClientID %>');
}
function validateRadioButtonList(radioButtonListId)
{
 var listItemArray = document.getElementsByName(radioButtonListId);
 var isItemChecked = false;

 for (var i=0; i<listItemArray.length; i++)
 {
  var listItem = listItemArray[i];

  if ( listItem.checked )
  {
   //alert(listItem.value);
   isItemChecked = true;
  }
 }

 if ( isItemChecked == false )
 {
  alert('Nothing is checked!');

  return false;
 }

 return true;
}
// -->
</script>

<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="return onButtonClick() ;" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

Comment: really thank u friend...but i already written function on button click...then how do add this to that...sry i have one above radiobuttonlist and two textboxes..i already wrote validation for that textboxes using javascript..i dont know how to do validate radio button list..so pls tell for this

Comment: string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload.FileName); string Imagename = objUser.UserID + filename; FileUpload.SaveAs(@"D:\Shop_Web_21-6-12\ShopMonkey\Images" + Imagename); uploaded file is not stored in given physical path?above is my coding.